# What's the purpose of invalidHandleValue in SafeHandle?

Tags: c#, safehandle

[The `SafeHandle` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3efd6ef.aspx) takes an `invalidHandleValue`. What is it used for if you have to implement `IsInvalid` anyway <del>because it has no idea which member variable holds the pointer</del> [I didn't know it implemented the `handle` member variable for you]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at it in DotPeek, I see that it is used only to initialize the `protected IntPtr handle` member variable.

```
protected SafeHandle(IntPtr invalidHandleValue, bool ownsHandle)
{
  this.handle = invalidHandleValue;
  ...
}
```

I'd say that the logic for this is something like:

- They want to guarantee that the `handle` member variable is initialized to something, so they make you pass the invalid value.
- There might be additional logic you want to test for in `IsInvalid`, so they don't bother to provide a default implementation (which would require saving the passed `invalidHandleValue` in the ctor as well.)

Comment: Oh... I didn't even know there was a `this.handle` member that it was implementing for me. I guess I should be using that rather than my own :-) This makes a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 1):

It is the default value of `handle` for when you call `new SafeHandleDerivedClass()` (the derived class may call `base.SetHandle(someValue)` in the constructor, but before that call the value will be whatever was passed in to the base class constructor).

Comment: I'm not sure how `SetHandleAsInvalid` *could* set `handle` back to that value, because it is never saved anywhere in the ctor.

Comment: Did you look at the code in DotPeek for `SetHandleAsInvalid`? It is just a call out to native code, who knows if it is storing a value there outside of `this.handle`. The only two ways for it to work is either it intercepts any calls to `IsInvalid` and returns false on it's behalf or it sets `this.handle` to a known invalid value.

Comment: Right, but the constructor would have to have saved the `invalidHandleValue` that you passed (which it doesn't).  I am very curious now though, how it is implemented.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.sethandleasinvalid.aspx): "Call the SetHandleAsInvalid method only when you know that your handle no longer references a resource. Doing so does not change the value of the handle field; it only marks the handle as closed. The handle might then contain a potentially stale value. The effect of this call is that no attempt is made to free the resources."

Comment: Thanks for getting me to look into that though - I've never bothered much with the `SafeHandle` internals.